# Google maps places/geocode API missing data for place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

When I search on maps.google.com for the address "21-6 Udagawacho, Shibuya, Tokyo Prefecture 150-0042, Japan", it comes up with a result that is the correct result at that exact address.

When I try querying google maps geocoder as well as place service with the same address, however, I always get no results. I've tried the geocoder as well as textSearch and radarSearch for the place service API.

Since the correct result came up on maps.google.com I know that google has the data for the place but why does it not come up in the API queries?